# Default Contact Search Profile

Tags: search

Why I cant see created profile in **Default Contact Search Profile**?

**My created profile:**

[image]

[image]

**Settings:**

[image]

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your profile includes Contact sub type fields. Adding these seems to make the profile you created unavailable in the Search preference options.
/civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1